# Is there shorthand in Rust for declaring a constructor that takes all the members of the struct?

Tags: rust

If you have a struct like so:

```rust
pub struct Foo {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i32,
    pub c: String,
    // and a bunch of other fields
}
```

Is there any way to declare a constructor that takes the members of the struct without copy/pasting all umpteen field names/types:

```rust
impl Foo {
    pub fn new(/* maaaagic */) {

    }
}
```

or do I have to do

```rust
impl Foo {
    pub fn new(
        a: i32,
        b: i32,
        c: String,
        // and a bunch of other args
    ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I observe that if **all** the fields are marked `pub`, you hardly need a constructor function as you can just use constructor syntax (`Foo { a: 10, b: some_variable, c }` etc.)

Comment: @trentcl I do some (type-preserving) logic on the inputs to the constructor before creating the struct instance, which is its raison d'etre.

Comment: If your constructor does logic to preserve type invariants, then you should have at least one non-`pub` field. I imagine your real code probably does have that - just pointing out the apparent inconsistency in this example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using [rust-analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/), there is a [generate new](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#generate_new) assist that does what you want.

[image]

Will generate:

```
impl Foo {
    pub fn new(a: i32, b: i32, c: String) -> Self { Self { a, b, c } }
}
```

Comment: I am indeed. That's a nice feature.